# Unable to open 2.0 zip archive

Tags: playframework

I downloaded play-2.0.zip from the website. When I try to unzip it (using 7-zip), I get an error can open  as archive

Comment: Is the Play 2.0 zip corrupted on the server? I only manage to download 49.5 MB as opposed to expected 89.4MB.

Comment: no, it worked great for me, are at work or behind a proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your download my not completed, so your file could be corrupt.
it has 93.754.223 bytes.

try: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm
it is a unix tool which is ported to windows.

in a command-shell type:

```
wget http://download.playframework.org/releases/play-2.0.zip
```

Comment: yes, that is what it seems like (my file is almost half the size). However, I tried the download multiple times and get the same problem (smaller size). I guess I will re-boot my computer to see if solves the problem

Comment: which operating system do you use?

Comment: That didi not work. I use Windows 7. The file I download is 50,692 KB

Comment: I am wondering if the archive has been corrupted

Comment: hopefully you can download that tool :D

Comment: I got wget and tried the command you advised. I get the error unable to resolve host address 'download.playframework.org'. I am at work and may something is blocking. I will have to try this from home

Comment: good luck! by the way it is a nice framework to 'play' with